# PFLogInViewController logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder is gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller, parse-ios-sdk

In a CustomLogInViewController class of mine subclass of PFLogInViewController, I had this kind of code:

```
@implementation CustomLogInViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    .......
    self.logInView.usernameField.attributedPlaceholder = sOME_VALUE;
    self.logInView.passwordField.attributedPlaceholder = sOME_OTHER_VALUE;
    .......
}
```

And this was generating no particular issue, but recently (after POD updates), I get this error messages:

```
Property 'attributedPlaceholder' cannot be found in forward class object 'PFTextField'
```

Did anyone else encounter this case and has a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually points out that Xcode can not recognize your symbol.

Try to insert this in your .h file:

```
#import PFTextField.h
```

Comment: OK, I will try. But this was not necessary before. Or did I do something without noticing ?